# (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI is never called

Tags: ios, objective-c, permissions, facebook-login

I followed all the instructions :

- `(BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI` is defined in my
  appdelegate header and implemenation
- `NSString *const FBSessionStateChangedNotification` is unique
- I use a `FBLoginView`, just like in Scrumptious sample app

But the openSessionWithAllowLoginUI is never ever called!

Since it's inside that method that permissions are set, I cannot change them.

```
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI
{
    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info", @"email"]
                                              allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error)
            {
                [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
            }];
}
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Didn't get ur problem. The method you said that you have to call

Comment: The problem is that the method, though it exists and is implemented, in never called during runtime.

Comment: some one has to call that method, it wont get call automatically. Actually from applicationDidFinishLaunching you have to call that method

Comment: Ok, I've called the method myself in `applicationDidBecomeActive` (`applicationDidFinishLaunching` was called either), but it prompts the user on startup. I want the user to be prompt on login.

Comment: u have to call like this [self openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:NO]

Comment: method is not getting called? tell properly. we dont have 6th sense..

Comment: I said `the openSessionWithAllowLoginUI is never ever called!`.

Comment: User @"Public_profile" in place of @"basic_info" like this: FBLoginView *loginView = 
    [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:
        @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"]];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating your facebook iOS sdk to latest version.

Use @"Public_profile" in place of @"basic_info" like this: FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"]];

Answer (score 0):

Facebook developer site they are suggesting, you have to start the section when applicationDidFinishLaunching itself. So you need to call **openSessionWithAllowLoginUI: NO** (no need to provide the login ui) from there. Dont worry if the user is not logged in this method wont do anything. In other case if the user is already authorized it will start a session for the user and change the state also(you will get notified) so you can set the login button accordingly. Finally wether this method failed to start a session allow the user to login through login button by calling **openSessionWithAllowLoginUI: YES**

Comment: I have implemented the login just like in the Scrumptious sample app. It is done by using the storyboard, adding a `UIView` and associating it with the class `FBLoginView`. The solution to my problem of requesting permission is to add `self.loginView.readPermissions = @[@"basic_info", @"email"];` in the `viewDidLoad` method (after creating an outlet for that). It is terribly docummented...

Comment: @btoueg If you solved your problem then post it as an answer and accept it so that others can come to know about the solution.